# How to connect github desktop to IBM hub.jazz.net

Tags: authentication, github, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

I am attempting to use GitHub Desktop with the Git repository on hub.jazz.net.  I cannot figure out how to authenticate with the repository, even after I have tried both the regular Git and Git Enterprise authentication methods.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the CLI set the remote host of the local repo to jazz.net using this format:

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://your_alias:your_IBM_ID_password@hub.jazz.net/alias/project_name
```

more [here](https://hub.jazz.net/docs/faq/#rtcgit%20%22here) on connecting local git clients.